# Getting value of textfield and copy-paste to another textfield in protractor

Tags: getelementbyid, gulp-protractor

Please help me. The output of the code below is "[Obj obj".

```
it('LeanAsset-input,function(){
    dv.sleep(5000);


    var PONum = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="pordr-create-content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input'));

    PONum.getText().then(function (text) {
            console.log(text);
    });
    element(by.xpath('//*[@id="pordr-create-content"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/input')).clear().sendKeys(PONum);

}');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass the web element instead of text in sendKeys.

You can try below the two solutions:

```
it('LeanAsset-input,function(){
    dv.sleep(5000);
    var PONum = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="pordr-create-content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input'));
    var text = PONum.getText();
    element(by.xpath('//*[@id="pordr-create-content"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/input')).clear().sendKeys(text );
}');
```

or

```
it('LeanAsset-input,function(){
    dv.sleep(5000);
    var PONum = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="pordr-create-content"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/input'));
    PONum.getText().then(function (text) {
        console.log(text);
        element(by.xpath('//*[@id="pordr-create-content"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/input')).clear().sendKeys(text);
    });
}');
```